# Google Sheets Vlookup does not return the correct value

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using the formula: =VLOOKUP(Y16,{U16:U20,V16:V20},2) but as can be seen in the images either it doesn't return the correct anwser or it doesn't return one at all.
Any idea on why this is?
Pictures of the problem:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzrVk.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mLzC.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVCG9.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMoKB.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGsNp.png

Answer (score 0):

[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

Although `is_sorted` is optional, you should set it to `FALSE` as your dataset isn't sorted.

```
=VLOOKUP(Y16,{U16:U20,V16:V20},2,FALSE)
```

Besides a `VLOOKUP`, you can also use an `INDEX` combined with a `MATCH`.

```
=INDEX(V16:V20,MATCH(Y16,U16:U20,0))
```